# Looping through a table and creating records in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, insert

I have a table called HoursWorkedInformation. It has 2 fields containing total hours worked from 2 other tables (Payroll timecards and medical task times [Credible]) containing detail records (you add up the hours in the detail records to get the total hours of each). The field names are TotalHours and CredibleHours.Each record is for a specific person identified by the field Credible_ID.

I have to compare the 2 values and if CredibleHours is greater than TotalHours then I have to create records in a 3rd table called EncounterData using the Credible Task hours detail records.
However the total # of EncounterData hours must match ONLY the total # of hours in the timecard data (the lesser of the 2 totals).
My mind is not getting it and I need some help.

I know what I want to do but am not sure how to do it.
What I want to do is get these totals off of HoursWorkedInformation table and then loop through the Credible hours data starting with the smallest and create Encounter hours up to the TotalHours amount.
This means my final Encounter Data record may only use part of the hours from 1 of the Credible hours records (the Credible hours are 10 but I only need to create 8 more hours for EncounterData).

Here is the Select statement that gets me the records I want to loop through.

```
SELECT
    ADP_ID,
    EmployeeInformationID,
    HoursWorkedInformation.Credible_ID,
    Credible_Hours,
    TotalHours,
    Credible_Hours - TotalHours as Diff,
    round(MergedDuration / 60, 2) as MergedDuration,
    PayPeriodID,
    EmployeeName,
    CredibleLocation,
    Program,
    CurPayerCode
FROM
    SEMHC_Admin2018.dbo.HoursWorkedInformation
    inner join TempCredibleImport on TempCredibleImport.Credible_ID = HoursWorkedInformation.Credible_ID
where
    PayPeriodID = @PayPeriodID
    and Credible_Hours > TotalHours
    and TotalHours > 0
order by
    HoursWorkedInformation.Credible_ID,
    TempCredibleImport.MergedDuration
```

Here is a insert statement I use when Credible Hours are <= TotalHours:

```
DECLARE @PayPeriodID as int = 2116
INSERT INTO
    EncounterData (
        Credible_ID,
        TotalHoursWorked,
        PayPeriodID,
        LocationNum,
        CostCenterNum,
        RecordActive,
        CreatedBy,
        CreateDate,
        ModifiedBy,
        ModifiedDate
    )
SELECT
    TempCredibleImport.Credible_ID,
    round(sum(TempCredibleImport.MergedDuration) / 60, 2) as hours,
    @PayPeriodID,
    CredibleXRef.LocationNum,
    CredibleXRef.CostCenterNum,
    1,
    'import',
    GETDATE(),
    'import',
    GETDATE()
FROM
    HoursWorkedInformation
    inner join TempCredibleImport on HoursWorkedInformation.PayPeriodID = @PayPeriodID
    and HoursWorkedInformation.Credible_ID = TempCredibleImport.Credible_ID
    left join CredibleXRef on CredibleXRef.CredibleLocation = TempCredibleImport.CredibleLocation
    and CredibleXRef.Program = TempCredibleImport.Program
    and CredibleXRef.CurPayer_Code = TempCredibleImport.CurPayerCode
where
    HoursWorkedInformation.Credible_ID is not null
    and HoursWorkedInformation.PayPeriodID = @PayPeriodID
    and HoursWorkedInformation.Credible_Hours <= HoursWorkedInformation.TotalHours
group by
    HoursWorkedInformation.EmployeeInformationID,
    HoursWorkedInformation.ADP_ID,
    HoursWorkedInformation.Credible_ID,
    TempCredibleImport.Credible_ID,
    TempCredibleImport.EmployeeName,
    CredibleXRef.LocationNum,
    CredibleXRef.CostCenterNum
```

Comment: Do the insert to the third table first, then the insert into the second table. You almost never need to "loop through" the results of a SQL query and it would be a horribly inefficient in this case.

Comment: Only EncounterData needs to be inserted. All of the other tables exist.The issue is how to get the TotalHours and CredibleHours from the HoursWorkedInformation table and then create the EncounterData table records using the credible records but only using part of the records (up to the total number of TotalHours).